# Alternative eval() to execute the string

Tags: javascript, string, object

My array is `A=['Apple','Peach','Orange']`in Javascript, someone pass me the string like "A[1]" , how to convert the string "A[1]" to an executable item, so I can get 'Peach' as the result.

`eval(A[1])` used to work but is not allowed here.

Comment: You can find the number between the square brackets (manually or using regular expressions) and parse it

Comment: Simple solution using regex: `A[+str.match(/^A\[(\d+)\]$/)[1]]` or `str.replace(/^A\[(\d+)\]$/, (m, i) => A[+i])`

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can parse out the variable and the index, then grab them off the window object.

```js
A=['Apple','Peach','Orange'];

let string = "A[1]";
let variable = string.match(/[^[]*/)[0];
let index = string.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1];
console.log(window[variable][index]);
```

Comment: This won't works if the variable name with more than one character. ( for example : ABC=['Apple','Peach','Orange']; )

Comment: Thanks, had to change `/[^[]/` to `/[^[]*/`

Comment: My variable names are:  A_B_C_1=[,,,], A_B_C_2=[,,,], A_B_C_3=[,,,], and the strings I got are like A_B_C_1[1], A_B_C_2[3], A_B_C_3[4];  eventually I need to get 3 values. How the regex will be? Thanks.

Comment: Why use two different RegExps and two different calls to `match` when you can have multiple capturing groups in a RegExp?

Answer (score 0):

You could split by apostrophe and then filter out the odd array members:

```js
var arrayString = "A=['Apple','Peach','Orange']"
var parsed = arrayString.split("'").filter(function(a, b){return b % 2});
console.log(parsed)
```